# Inherited widgets and navigator

Tags: flutter

I found some answers about this [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328362/get-access-to-the-context-of-inheritedwidget/49329255#49329255), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263068/inheritedwidget-the-getter-was-called-on-null-after-navigator-push)] but none of them completely answer my question.

I'm going to be using the package [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to describe my question because it greatly reduces the boilerplate code.

What I want to do is to inject a dependency when (and only when) a route is called. I can achieve that by doing something like this on `onGenerateRoute`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Routes Demo',
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
            case '/firstPage':
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => Provider(
                      builder: (_) => MyComplexClass(),
                      child: FirstPage(),
                    ),
              );
            case '/secondPage':
              return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondPage());
            default:
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                      body: Center(
                        child: Text('Route does not exists'),
                      ),
                    ),
              );
          }
        });
  }
}

class MyComplexClass {
  String message = 'UUUH I am so complex';
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go to first page'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/firstPage');
              }),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myComplexClass = Provider.of<MyComplexClass>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text(myComplexClass.message),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go to second page'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondPage');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myComplexClass = Provider.of<MyComplexClass>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(myComplexClass.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine for '/firstPage', but as soon as I push another route from inside 'firstPage' the context is lost and I loose access to `MyComplexClass`, since the navigator stays at the top of the tree together with MaterialApp the next route will loose the context where MyComplexClass was injected, I cannot manage to find a elegant solution to this.

This is the navigator stack we end up with:
[image: navigation stack]

As we can see `SecondPage` is not a child of `Provider`, hence the problem.

I don't want to inject all dependencies I have all at once on top of MainApp, I want to inject them as they're needed.
I considered creating new navigators each time I need another "fold", but that seems to become really messy very quickly.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: `"I cannot manage to find a elegant solution to this."` - for what exactly? cannot you access your `Inherited`Widget` from the second route or what?

Comment: Yes, once I push a new route inside '/foo' it loses the context that the `InheritedWidget` was on.

Comment: so you mean that `inheritFromWidgetExactType` method returns null? if so, post your code

Comment: I edited the question and added the complete code example so my question becomes clearer.

Comment: so make your `Provider` as a parent of `MyApp` for example (or as a parent of `MaterialApp`)

Comment: This is what I described in the question what I **don't** want to do. Currently I have a bunch of providers in my code and it quickly becomes out of hand to just inject everything from the `MaterialApp`.

Comment: What I want to do is to create `MyComplexClass` only when pushing for `FirstPage`, and I want to be able to access this class in the pages that `FirstPage` is able to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following examples, both the route `/` and `/login` can access `Provider.of<int>`, but the route `/other` can't.

There are two solutions:

- A `StatefulWidget` combined with a `Provider.value` that wraps each route.

Example:

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  int myState = 42;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => Provider.value(value: myState, child: Home()),
        '/login': (_) => Provider.value(value: myState, child: Login()),
        '/other': (_) => Other(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

- A private placeholder type that wraps `MaterialApp` combined with `ProxyProvider`:

Example:

```
class _Scope<T> {
  _Scope(this.value);

  final T value;
}

// ...

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Provider(
    builder: (_) => _Scope(42),
    child: MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => ProxyProvider<_Scope<int>, int>(
            builder: (_, scope, __) => scope.value, child: Home()),
        '/login': (_) => ProxyProvider<_Scope<int>, int>(
            builder: (_, scope, __) => scope.value, child: Login()),
        '/other': (_) => Other(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```